# Angular change scope/zone for events managed outside Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using a external library in Angular 6 which adds event listeners which the callbacks are configurable. In particular, I use `flowchart.js` but I guess the problem is applicable to any other library.

In my case, `flowchart.js` allows to set callbacks for `onClick` events. However, it does that by adding a function to the `Window` context (details [here](https://github.com/adrai/flowchart.js/commit/5156d9a0fd86a86afb56b96b93bde8c721891abe#diff-0e034bd7da7d51bb47206ad0993196c0R88)). It defines the callback by: `window[options.function](evt,options);`.

**What I want**: I want to be able to use a callback from my Angular class which has access to the data inside Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Since, I didn't find the solution trivial (even though I am not a web developer and therefore not expert in Angular), I would like to share my solution, and see if there are any other improvements or security risks from this solution.

While debugging and following some call stacks, I came across the concept of Zone, and led me to this article [Using Zones in Angular for better performance](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/21/using-zones-in-angular-for-better-performance.html). There was this interesting line  `window.document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove.bind(this));` within an Angular class! So, I interpreted the `this.mouseMove.bind(this)`, as the callback with implicit binding the the class. Exactly what I was looking for. (In python, this is similar to `MyClass.my_function(self), or self.my_function`, where the class is provided in the function call.

So, here was my solution with the source code:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

import * as fc from 'flowchart.js';
import { ActorDialogService } from '../actor-dialog.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'flow-chart',
  templateUrl: '<div id="diagram"></div>'
})
export class FlowChartComponent implements OnInit{

    private diagramTest: string = `
    st=>start: Start|past:$nodeTriggerFunction
    e=>end: End|future:$renderIpuDialog
    op1=>operation: My Operation|past
    op2=>operation: Stuff|current
    sub1=>subroutine: My Subroutine|invalid
    cond=>condition: Yes
    or No?|approved:>http://www.google.com
    c2=>condition: Good idea|rejected
    io=>inputoutput: catch something...|future

    st->op1(right)->cond
    cond(yes, right)->c2
    cond(no)->sub1(left)->op1
    c2(yes)->io->e
    c2(no)->op2->e`
    private diagram = fc.parse(this.diagramTest);

    nodeTriggerFunction(event, node){
        console.log("flochart-log with {} - {}", event, node);
    }

    renderDialog(event, node){
        // event callback from window
        this.actorDialogService.push(null);
    }

    constructor(private window: Window,
        private actorDialogService: ActorDialogService,     
        private el: ElementRef
    ) {
        // add function to the window, with the context binding
        window['renderDialog']= this.renderDialog.bind(this);
        // add function to the window but it will be call as static, no context
        window['nodeTriggerFunction'] = this.nodeTriggerFunction;

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.diagram.drawSVG('diagram')
    }
}
```